# List Based PHP Interface for multiple actions on multiple elements

Tags: php, html, forms

I've seen this done in a lot of places. I am wondering what the best way to go about implementing this is.

Basically what you have is a list of users. The interface shows each user on a line (table?) and has check boxes for options that are displayed as columns. Action buttons on bottom and/or top of the table allow execution of the command, while buttons within each row of each user also allow the user to act directly upon that element.

Should this be done as a basic HTML table? Or is there a something already in place for this type of form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit upon one correct usage of a table: **tabular data**. If you've got a **table** of users and settings, it is <del>perfectly correct</del> *encouraged* to use a table, as it is semantically appropriate.

The difficulty may lie in how you want to mark up your form. You're likely going to want to put the table in a form element so that you can place your input elements anywhere within the table.